# jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string

Tags: jq

```
$ jq '.y | gsub(","; "-")' <<< '{"y": "a,b"}'
"a-b"
$ jq '.y | gsub(","; "-")' <<< '{"x": "a"}'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

I got the above error. I can use if-else-end statement to solve the problem. But it is a little verbose.

What is the most succinct way to fix the error so that .y is still accessed with "," replaced by "-", but when .y does not exist, an empty string will be printed?

Answer (score 3):

Add the [Error Suppression Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression/OptionalOperator:?) `?` which defaults to `empty`

```sh
jq '.y | gsub(","; "-")?'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uc67iWWKFj)

You may additionally add a default alternative using the [Alternative Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) `//`

```sh
jq '.y | gsub(","; "-")? // ""'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mTOV01-YLG)